# Variable alignment in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to set an alignment rule when declaring variables only using Prettier:

```
const variable1  = 'new thing';
let   v2         = 50;
v2              += 1;
```

I tried [`Align`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steve8708.Align) extension for vscode which didn't work at all.

Are there any settings in vscode and or Prettier I could apply?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align works good

Comment: thanks for the comment, it looks great so far!